# How to interpret javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, xsd, unmarshalling

I receive this error when i attempt to convert an xml file to its java counterpart :

```
09.09.2013 13:58:26 ERROR [manager.getContentsUnmarshalled():154] There was an error parsing the file: "props.xml". JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"newImageOverlay"). Expected elements are <{}GenericData>,<{}VirtualComponent>,<{}application_constants>,<{}channel>
```

I think this error is signifying that there is an unexpected element in the xml file ?

In the exception message how is jaxb identifying the "Expected elements" ? Where are identifiers `<{}GenericData>,<{}VirtualComponent>,<{}application_constants>,<{}channel>` specified ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this entry to my application context file :

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.MyGeneratedClass"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```